# Images not displayed in wiki pages after upgrade

Tags: mediawiki

I recently upgraded a Mediawiki 1.18 installation to version 1.23 following [the guide](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Upgrading).  All of the data and accounts seem to have transferred.  In order to upload files again, I had to run the following:

```
sudo chown -R www-data images
sudo chmod -R 755 images/
```

I can now upload images.  At `Special:ListFiles`, I can see all of the uploads, and images are displayed properly, both at full-size and as thumbnails.  However, when I include them in a page, they are not rendered as images. For example, `File:Margin_padding.png` when included by `[[File:Margin padding.png]]`, is rendered as the following:

[image: File rendering]

Most of the similar sounding issues I've found are due to bad mime-type detection, but according to mediawiki and the PHP interactive shell, the example image is `image/php`.  I have the same symptoms for images uploaded before the migration and after.  Are there any settings that could result in this behavior?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the `LocalSettings.php` file from version 1.18, I had `$wgUrlProtocols[] = "file:";`.  As of version 1.20.2, [this breaks image embedding](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgUrlProtocols).  The solution is to use `file://` instead.

```
$wgUrlProtocols[] = "file://";
```

The credit goes to Carmela on the #mediawiki IRC channel.

Comment: thank you - googled the whole internet and you gave the only correct answer.

Comment: @jiaoziren Carmela did. ;)

Answer (score 1):

What solved it for me was adding this in `LocalSettings.php`:

```
$wgHashedUploadDirectory = true;
```

[This setting](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgHashedUploadDirectory) was probably already set to `true` on first installation but went missing (so false?) after an upgrade.

Since this determines where and how images are uploaded (into `images/` in bulk or into subdirectories of `images/`) changing it on an already configured wiki -- i.e. with images already uploaded -- will break it and the wiki will look for images in the wrong place / using the wrong method.

Comment: YOU are a lifesaver. THANK YOU! This worked after upgrading from 1.25 to 1.36 in one step, while regenerating the `LocalSettings.php.`